# Drag and Drop - change value input field

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, smarty

I need you help with a drag and drop function for tables. 
I use the drag and drop function from: http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

So I created a table. Every row has an own id. 
Draging the rows works fine. Every row has an input field where the number of the ordering ist shown.
Now when I drag one of the rows, I want that value changed. For example: 
If I drag line number 3 to top (to row 2), then number 3 needs to change to 2 and number 3 should change to number 2.

Here ist the code I use:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="articletable">

         <tbody>
        {section name=i loop=$daten_art_top}
            <tr id="{$daten_art_top[i].sequence}">
                <td><input type="text" value="{$daten_art_top[i].sequence}" class="span2" style="text-align: center" id="sequence_{$daten_art_top[i].sequence}" /></td>
                <td><a href="index.php?op=editart&artid={$daten_art_top[i].ID}">{$daten_art_top[i].title}</a></td>
                <td><small>{$daten_art_top[i].date_created|date_format:"d.m.Y"}</small></td>
                <td>
                    categorie_number


                </td>   
                <td></td>       
             </tr>       
        {/section}
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
// Drag and Drop für Tabelle
$("#articletable").tableDnD( {
    onDragClass: "myDragClass",
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
        var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
        $('#sequence_'+row.id).val(row.id);
    }
});
```

Do you have a idea how I can do this?